# Convergence of $\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\frac{\ln n}{n^p}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

My real analysis textbook uses this sum as an example for a sum with positive general terms.
I understand why the general term of the sum converges to zero.

In the solution it is stated that convergence of this sum can be shown for $p>1$ by comparing it to $\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\frac{1}{n^{p-\epsilon}}$ where $0<\epsilon<1-p$.

I don't understand how there can be no possible values of $\epsilon$. And if I consider the $p$ to have different values in the two sums I still don't know how to show convergence by comparison.

Comment: Hint: for $x>0$, $\log x < x$. Thus $\log n < \frac{1}{\varepsilon }n^\varepsilon$ for all $n\geq 1$ and $\varepsilon>0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $x>0$, $\log x < x$. Thus, $\log n < \frac{1}{\varepsilon }n^\varepsilon$ for all $n\geq 1$ and $\varepsilon>0$. If $p>1$, then there is an $\varepsilon>0$ such that $p > 1 + \varepsilon  > 1$. With this $\varepsilon$,
$$
\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{\log n}}{{n^p }}}  \le \frac{1}{\varepsilon }\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{n^{p - \varepsilon } }}}  < \infty ,
$$
since $p-\varepsilon>1$, and we know that $\sum\nolimits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{n^\alpha  }}}$ converges for any $\alpha>1$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $a_n = \frac{1}{n^{p-\epsilon}}$ with $0 < \epsilon < 1 - p$ and $b_n = \frac{\log n}{n^p}$. Then
\begin{equation}
\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\frac{a_n}{b_n} = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{n^{\epsilon}}{\log n} = \infty.
\end{equation}
Since $\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty a_n < \infty$ the comparison test allows you to conclude. If you have trouble showing that $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{n^\epsilon}{n^p} = \infty$ for any $\epsilon > 0$ you could use L'Hopital's rule for example.